# How to change the formatting/font of page numbers in latex?

Tags: text, latex, typesetting, xelatex, page-numbering

I don't just mean how to switch to roman numerals, I want to change the font face and size. I'm currently using the article class, but I can't see any particular part of it responsible for the footer, so I wonder if this might not apply to a lot of classes.

Edit: I don't need to make a custom page layout or pagestyle, necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `fancyhdr` package.

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/